# $\forall x\in R,$find the range of the function $f(x)=\cos x(\sin x+\sqrt{\sin^2x+\sin^2\alpha});\alpha\in[0,\pi]$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

$\forall x\in R,$find the range of the function $f(x)=\cos x(\sin x+\sqrt{\sin^2x+\sin^2\alpha});\alpha\in[0,\pi]$

---

$f(x)=\cos x(\sin x+\sqrt{\sin^2x+\sin^2\alpha});\alpha\in[0,\pi]$
$f'(x)=\cos x(\cos x+\frac{\sin x\cos x}{\sqrt{\sin^2x+\sin^2\alpha}})-\sin x(\sin x+\sqrt{\sin^2x+\sin^2\alpha})$
I am stuck here and could not find the minimum and maximum values of $f(x),$The answer given is $-\sqrt{1+\sin^2\alpha}\leq f(x)\leq\sqrt{1+\sin^2\alpha}$.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1723636/maximum-value-of-fx-cos-x-left-sin-x-sqrt-sin2x-sin2a-right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$y=\cos x\left[\sin x+\sqrt{\sin^2 x+\sin^2 a}\right] = \sin x\cdot \cos x+\cos x\cdot \sqrt{\sin^2 x+\sin^2 a}$$

Now Using $\bf{Cauchy\; Schwartz\; Inequality}$

We get $$(\sin^2 x+\cos ^2 x)\cdot \left[\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x+\sin^2 a\right]\geq \left(\sin x\cdot \cos x+\cos x\cdot \sqrt{\sin^2 x+\sin^2 a}\right)^2$$

So we get $$y^2\leq (1+\sin^2 a)\Rightarrow |y| \leq\sqrt{1+\sin^2 a}$$

So we get $$-\sqrt{1+\sin^2 a}\leq y \leq \sqrt{1+\sin^2 a}.$$

Answer (score 1):

You're derivative need work. $$f'(x)=-\sin(\sin(x)+\sqrt{\sin^2 x+\sin^2\alpha})\left(\cos x+\frac{2\sin x\cos x}{\sqrt{\sin^2 x+\sin^2\alpha}}\right).$$

Now determine when this is zero, which is precisely when $$\sin(\sin(x)+\sqrt{\sin^2 x+\sin^2\alpha})=0,$$ or $$\cos x+\frac{2\sin x\cos x}{\sqrt{\sin^2 x+\sin^2\alpha}}=0.$$