# Minimum and maximum of $y=\cos\theta(\sin\theta+\sqrt{\sin^2\theta+\sin^2\alpha})$

Tags: trigonometry

The minimum and maximum values of expression $y=\cos\theta(\sin\theta+\sqrt{\sin^2\theta+\sin^2\alpha})$ is:

My attempt is as follows:-

**Attempt $1$:**

$$y=\cos\theta\sin\theta+\sqrt{\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\alpha\cos^2\theta}$$
$$y=\dfrac{\sin2\theta}{2}+\sqrt{\dfrac{\sin^22\theta}{4}+\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta}$$

Here the term $\cos^2\theta$ created the issue and I didn't find any way to proceed further.

**Attempt $2$:**

Rationalizing

$$y=\dfrac{\cos\theta\cdot\sin^2\alpha}{\sin\theta-\sqrt{\sin^2\theta+\sin^2\alpha}}$$
$$y=\dfrac{\sin^2\alpha}{\tan\theta-\sqrt{\tan^2\theta+\sin^2\alpha\sec^2\theta}}$$

Here I was not able to comprehend how to get minimum and maximum value.

**Attempt 3:**

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=-\sin\theta(\sin\theta+\sqrt{\sin^2\theta+\sin^2\alpha})+\cos\theta\left(\cos\theta+\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{\sin^2\theta+\sin^2\alpha}}\cdot2\sin\theta\cos\theta\right)$$

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=-\sin\theta(\sin\theta+\sqrt{\sin^2\theta+\sin^2\alpha})+\cos^2\theta\cdot\dfrac{\sin\theta+\sqrt{\sin^2\theta+\sin^2\alpha}}{\sqrt{\sin^2\theta+\sin^2\alpha}}$$

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=(\sin\theta+\sqrt{\sin^2\theta+\sin^2\alpha})\left(-\sin\theta+\dfrac{\cos^2\theta}{\sqrt{\sin^2\theta+\sin^2\alpha}}\right)$$

Now from here it will be very difficult to decide about the maximum and minimum value.

Any inputs?

Comment: Take the derivative in respect to $\alpha$; is is zero if $\theta\in\{\pi/2,3\pi/2\}$ or $\alpha\in\{0,\pi,2\pi\}$.

Comment: You have to push some more, I would continue with Attempt 3.

Comment: actually I would prefer derivative approach at very last, I am searching for some approach other than derivative.

Comment: Are you trying to find the min and max with respect to $\alpha$ or $\theta\ or both? In the last case, you must use partial derivatives.

Comment: $$y=\dfrac{\sin2\theta}{2}+\sqrt{\dfrac{\sin^22\theta}{4}+\sin^2\alpha\cos^2\theta}$$ in attempt 1 , last step

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1723636/maximum-value-of-fx-cos-x-left-sin-x-sqrt-sin2x-sin2a-right

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximum value of $f(x) = \cos x \left( \sin x + \sqrt {\sin^2x +\sin^2a}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1723636/maximum-value-of-fx-cos-x-left-sin-x-sqrt-sin2x-sin2a-right)

Answer (score 1):

Continue with the derivative approach,

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{(\sin\theta+\sqrt{\sin^2\theta+\sin^2\alpha})
(\cos^2\theta-\sin\theta\sqrt{\sin^2\theta+\sin^2\alpha})}{\sqrt{\sin^2\theta+\sin^2\alpha}}=0$$

which leads to

$$\cos^2\theta-\sin\theta\sqrt{\sin^2\theta+\sin^2\alpha}=0$$

Write $\cos^2\theta = 1-\sin^2\theta$ and the locations of the extrema are found at

$$\sin\theta = \frac1{\sqrt{2+\sin^2\alpha}},\>\>\>\>
\cos\theta = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1+\sin^2\alpha}{2+\sin^2\alpha}}$$

Then, it is straightforward to determine that the extrma of the expression

$$y(\theta)=\cos\theta(\sin\theta+\sqrt{\sin^2\theta+\sin^2\alpha})$$

are

$$y_{max} = \sqrt{1+\sin^2\alpha},\>\>\>\>\>y_{min} =- \sqrt{1+\sin^2\alpha}$$