# Maxima and minima of trigonometric expressions

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, maxima-minima

Find the maxima and minima of the following:

1.$f(x)= \cos x \left(\sin x+\sqrt{\sin^2x+\sin^2d} \right)$

2.$ f(x)=\frac{tan{(x+a)}}{tan{(x-a)}}$,

($a,d$ are constants)

**Backround**:This would be a straight forward problem if we use calculus.This problem is from S.L Loney, and we are not expected to use calculus. I actually don,t know how to start.It would be  helpful if i could get a hint.

Here are somethings ,I think will work:

I know that $$-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\le a\sin x+b\cos x\le \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$.

Also I was run out of ideas of using inequalities like C-S,Am-Gm as the terms need not be positive.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1723636/maximum-value-of-fx-cos-x-left-sin-x-sqrt-sin2x-sin2a-right

Comment: @labbhattacharjee  very nice link !thank you , but a similar method doesn't seem to work for f(x)=tan(x+a)/tan(x-a), Any ideas?

Comment: How can there be limits for $f(x)=\frac{\tan{(x+a)}}{\tan{(x-a)}}$? Assume $a$ is not an integer multiple of $\pi/2$ and let $x = a + \epsilon$. Then for $\epsilon \to \pm 0$, we have $f(x) =  \frac{\tan{(2a)}}{\tan{(\epsilon)}} \to \pm \infty$. So the only (exceptional) nontrivial case to consider would be if  $a$ is an integer multiple of $\pi/2$.

Comment: @Andreas there is no global maxima/minima but there are local ones, which I presume the question was referring to. You can plot the graph in Desmos to get a clearer idea